# Github - Do I need multiple SSH keys for different projects? (MacOS)

Tags: git, macos, github, ssh, ssh-keys

I am configuring git & github for a friend who's new to coding. He already has an ssh key on his mac, which is tied to his organization (which a colleague created for him). I have now created a new github account for him for a project we're doing together. Can I just use the ssh key that's already on his mac? Or will i need to generate a new one?

If I do need to generate a new one, is there anything I gotta watch out for?

Answer (score 3):

If you add the matching public key to the Github account, he can access Github with the private key he already has.

However, as you describe above

> which a colleague created for him

I would recommend that he generates a new key by himself (which he is sure nobody else has) and then use this key to access Github.

btw. some articles to read

- https://www.beyondtrust.com/blog/entry/ssh-key-management-overview-6-best-practices
- https://www.reddit.com/r/linux/comments/pas9s/ssh_public_key_auth_best_practices/
- https://www.ssh.com/ssh/keygen/